# javascript - parameter one of two possible values

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, in javascript (no typescript), to specify that the parameter of a method  has to be "one of" [value1, value2]?

For example, if I have a function:

```
const handleCommentAction = (action) => {
    if (action === "add") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments + 1);
    } else if (action === "delete") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments - 1);
    }
}
```

if there any way to specify that action has to be one of ["add", "delete"] ?

```
// Something like this...
const handleCommentAction = (action: ["add", "delete"]) => {
```

or is impossible?

Comment: JavaScript does not have anything resembling this, but [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) does.

Comment: Would TypeScript be a valid answer?  Or is this just for JavaScript?

Comment: @Wyck no typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be enforced at runtime only by throwing an error or something:

```
const handleCommentAction = (action) => {
    if (action === "add") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments + 1);
    } else if (action === "delete") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments - 1);
    } else {
        throw new Error('wrong parameter');
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) to indicate that the argument must be of a particular type:

```
/**
 * @param {'add' | 'delete'} action - The action to perform
 */
const handleCommentAction = (action) => {
    if (action === "add") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments + 1);
    } else if (action === "delete") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments - 1);
    }
};
```

But this is only *documentation*, not a *requirement* of consumers of `handleCommentAction`.

A more elaborate solution (definitely worth it in larger projects, but arguably overkill for small scripts) would be to use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or some other type-aware system:

```
const handleCommentAction = (action: 'add' | 'delete') => {
    if (action === "add") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments + 1);
    } else if (action === "delete") {
        setTotalComments(totalComments - 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Note: asker has specifically requested no typescript, although typescript may be useful to others.